# How to set a dynamic choices tuple based on other model field values

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model with 2 fields:

- A `ManyToMany` field that contains a number of users who can approve a task (`approvers`); and
- An `IntegerField` that contains a choices tuple to return the current step of the task (`step`).

```
    class Task(models.Model):
        approvers = models.ManyToManyField(
            get_user_model(),
            through='TaskStep'
        )
        step = IntegerField(
            choices=STEP_CHOICES
        )
```

I want to allow users to define the number of approvers, but also dynamically create a choice for each `approver` in `step`.

How can I programmatically define the choices in my tuple to cover the number of users in the ManyToMany field?

For example, if there are 3 approvers, the result would be:

```
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Step 1'),
        (2, 'Step 2'),
        (3, 'Step 3'),
    )
```

If there were 5 users, the result would be:

```
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Step 1'),
        (2, 'Step 2'),
        (3, 'Step 3'),
        (4, 'Step 4'),
        (5, 'Step 5'),
    )
```

Comment: I think you can't define the dynamic choices in model itself, but what are you trying to do? In form you can generate the choice dynamically though?

Comment: @MohitSolanki I could put them through `__init__` can't I? I am trying to create a model field to tack the status of the task effectively

Comment: @alias51 I don't think you can pull them through into with the `__init__` method because the fields/choices represent the database, which is changed through migrations. As mentioned in a previous comment, you can do this for forms however. I guess you could also create a `Step` model which has a `step_number` field and a `ForeignKey` to the `Task`, then create the `Step` instances when the `Task` is created? - Happy to put this in an answer to show implementation if you would find it useful.